# How to include startup script in docker compose when deploying to Azure App

Tags: azure, docker, containers

In my docker-compose.yml, I include some start up scripts for mongodb as follows:

```
volumes:
 - db-data:/data/db
 - ./mongo-entrypoint:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

How can I achieve the same thing on azure app service? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, I recommend you use the Azure CLI command to achieve it. See the CLI command [`az webapp create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-create) with the parameter `--startup-file`, the thing you need to take care is that it is just useful for Linux.

Another way for you is that copy the startup file inside the image and set it to run with `CMD` inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: Hi Charles, sorry for late reply. For the CMD way, do you mean I have to create my own mongodb image and push it to my azure container registry? Thanks.

Comment: @nathan1658 Yes, for the CMD command, I mean to create new image with copying the startup file into the image in the Dockerfile.